# More flexibility in defining input arguments for a function in python?

Tags: python, function, class, arguments, parameter-passing

I have the following function which I'm using to run analysis.

When I set `run_analysis_1 = True`, it should run the whole first piece of analysis, which outputs plots 1, 2 and 3. When I set `run_analysis_2 = True`, it should run the whole second piece of analysis, which outputs plots 4, 5 and 6.

```
def save_locally(self,
                 run_all_analysis: bool = False,
                 run_analysis_1: bool = False,
                 run_analysis_2: bool = False):

    if run_analysis_1 = True
        plot_1 # some function that creates plot 1 + saves to local folder
        plot_2 # some function that creates plot 2 + saves to local folder
        plot_3 # some function that creates plot 3 + saves to local folder
    
    if run_analysis_2 = True
        plot_4 # some function that creates plot 4 + saves to local folder
        plot_5 # some function that creates plot 5 + saves to local folder
        plot_6 # some function that creates plot 6 + saves to local folder
```

I would like a lot of flexibility in choosing what plots I would like to run, such that, I am able to:

1. Run the whole of a piece of analysis (for example, run all components of analysis 1 to output plots 1,2 and 3)
2. Run a part of the analysis (for example, just run plot 1 from analysis 1)

So it looks something like the below...

```
save_locally(run_analysis_1.plot_1=True, run_analysis_2.all=True)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you;

- Store all plots from an analysis in its own class
- Custom `all` attribute to store all defined plots in one list
- Change signature of `save_locally` to take `*args`

Would let you call your function pretty cleanly like this:

`save_locally(Analysis1.plot1, Analysis1.plot2, Analysis2.all)`

---

```py
from itertools import chain

class _Analysis:
    all = ...
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        cls.all = [value for key, value in cls.__dict__.items() if not key.startswith("_")]

class Analysis1(_Analysis):
    plot1 = "a"
    plot2 = "b"
    plot3 = "c"

class Analysis2(_Analysis):
    plot4 = "d"
    plot5 = "e"
    plot6 = "f"


def save_locally(*plots):
    plots = chain(*plots)  # Flatten - lets us write Analysis.all without *
    for plot in plots:
        print(plot, end=" ")  # Do whatever with plot

save_locally(Analysis1.plot1, Analysis1.plot2, Analysis2.all)

>>> a b d e f
```

Comment: Amazing, that is what I was after!